# Maven dependency updates report takes hours to complete

Tags: performance, maven, jenkins, xerces, versions-maven-plugin

I have task to run Jenkins job witch would report newer version of libraries.
I think that these would do what I need:

```
org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.5:plugin-updates-report
org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.5:property-updates-report
org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.5:dependency-updates-report
```

Job runs correctly but when it reaches project last artifact (artifact xerces:xercesImpl: checking for updates from default) it stucks for few hours. I was able to reproduce it locally. I've tried to change plugin version but none of them worked better. I checked if

```
versions:display-dependency-updates
versions:display-plugin-updates
versions:display-property-updates
```

would work as long as report. But these goals finished with "BUILD SUCCESS" in a bit more than half an hour.

What is wrong and why only report stuck on xerces?
Maybe it is possible to set these commands

```
versions:display-dependency-updates
versions:display-plugin-updates
versions:display-property-updates
```

to make an ouputFile in html like report does?

Comment: Check your repository manager if correctly configured to create metadata...Are you using a repository manager ?

Comment: I'm quite new with Jenkins and maven. When I started I just installed Maven and other programs like Mercurial and Docker but none of additional programs associated with Maven. That's for my local computer.
Jenkins is used by many colleagues so I think that there things should be configured correctly.