# Offer alternatives to versions:dependency-updates-report

Tags: maven, report, versions-maven-plugin

I have 
[problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588848/maven-dependency-updates-report-takes-hours-to-complete) 
with

```
versions:dependency-updates-report
```

which I cannot solve. Maybe someone could offer some alternative which would make  similar html report with those columns (Next Version, Next Incremental, Next Minor, Next Major)?

Comment: Which kind of problems?

Comment: I have quite big project to check and problem is that it takes few days to check everything. But if running " versions:display-dependency-updates"
it takes way less time. You can press on word  "problem" to read more about it

Comment: As I mentioned in the linked post. Check the configuration of Nexus and try to figure out what the real issue is...asking several times the same things will not help...